# Fake microphone in protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

In my test scenario, I want to play test sound when I click "push-to-talk" button.

Set up chrome with the following capabilities `--use-fake-device-for-media-stream`, `--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream`, `--use-file-for-fake-audio-capture=./media/sample.wav`.

But how to start playing this sample.wav?